# Why does my application not use 100% of the available heap before crashing?

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

[image: heap track]

Here's JVisualVM's heap monitor for my application. (yes I know I have a memory leak).

I'm wondering why it doesn't use that last 30mb before I get an out of memory exception.

Comment: What JVM are you using, what's your command line for running the application, and what is taking up your memory? Notice it tried garbage collecting earlier when it reached that 30MB point, so possible you have 30MB configured for your Young Generation space, and you're eating up memory with existing objects (in the Old Generation space).

Comment: how would I configure my "young generation" space?

Comment: If you're using the Oracle JVM, see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html) for tuning parameters. Look under "Sizing the Generations".

Comment: What if the last element it tries to allocate would actually need more than 30 MB. I doubt you would see it actually claim memory then, it would probably see that it doesnt have enough memory to claim and then crash before actually claiming the rest. I am not expert on this topic though.